# Difference in permission between "C" and "extern C"

Tags: c++, c, qt

I am trying to use a function in C in a C++ function.

Part of this function involves using fopen:

```
FILE * fd = NULL;
fd = fopen("/sys/platform/dacc/config","w");
if(!fd){
    perror("Platform configuration failed:");
    return -1;
}
fwrite(conf,1,4096,fd);
fclose(fd);
return 0;
```

I had some code doing this in C which worked how I wanted. I would like to connect this operation to a button using Qt, and after asking a question about it here, I was able to call the function using "extern C" to include it into my c++ code.

Now that I have this same code running in C++ however, I am no longer able to open the file in question. Instead I now get a null returned by fopen, and perror gives the message

```
Platform configuration failed: Permission Denied
```

This is confusing to me, as my C test code was run from a terminal without any elevation, so I didn't permissions should be any kind of issue.

Is there a difference in what permissions are available to a program running C code and those available to a C++ program including C code?

Comment: No, there is not. The relevant permissions are based on your user account, which should be the same in both cases, and maybe SELinux or something, which I’d expect to do the same thing.

Comment: No, there are no differences. Neither with Perl, Java, Python, PHP, Haskell, ...

Comment: No, I doubt this has anything to do with C vs C++ (other than a bug in your code).

Comment: I'd expect something in `/sys` to be writable only by root. Did you run the C++ application as root?

Comment: Run the program under `strace` to find out whether the system call that's failing is actually the `open` of `/sys/platform/dacc/config`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be **no difference in permissions** when using the "extern C" keyword. This just prevents the compiler from mangling the function's name.